# Formatting A Date Field in SPList

Tags: sharepoint-online, splist, date

We have a requirement in which a custom date field is displayed in the format:

> YearMonthDay

example:

```
20181031
```

How can I achieve this at the Site Column level? Does it require JSON Column formatting? I do NOT want to use a Calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to apply custom string formats using column formatting currently. Please see custom formatter reference
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Operator supported for date fields are:

```
toLocaleString()
toLocaleDateString()
toLocaleTimeString()
```

So I think calculated column is your best option.

Comment: I specifically stated no Calculated columns. They still have the same issues they did years ago. You can't paste in data because they're read only. And why does this work =TEXT(Created,"YYYYMMdd") while this doesn't =TEXT(MyDateField,"YYYYMMdd")... makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean that =TEXT(MyDateField,"YYYYMMdd") doesn't work? Please share more information about it.